Unable to Retrieve Data from AWS Glacier to S3 Bucket: Errors Encountered
I’m trying to retrieve archived data from AWS Glacier and move it to an S3 bucket, but I’m encountering issues during the process. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the InitiateJob operation: User: arn:aws:iam::806293447701:user/salman is not authorized to perform: glacier:InitiateJob on resource: arn:aws:glacier:us-west-2:AKIA3XOWVUQKSRK6R5N4:vaults/bitcoin-class

Here’s an example of my CLI command:
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id AKIA3XOWVUQKSRK6R5N4 --vault-name bitcoin-class --job-parameters file://inventory-retrieval.json
In Addition, I have already included the 'Permission Policies' for this user. Policy name: AmazonGlacierFullAccess & AmazonS3FullAccess.
Questions:

Is there a specific configuration I might have overlooked in the restore process?

How can I debug why the data is not appearing in the S3 bucket?

Are there additional steps needed for transferring restored data to S3?


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Try to use this command and make sure that the user has the InitiateJob permission;
aws iam simulate-principal-policy --policy-source-arn arn:aws:iam::806293447701:user/salman --action-names glacier:InitiateJob --resource-arns arn:aws:glacier:us-west-2:806293447701:vaults/bitcoin-class 

if it shows Deny, inspect explicit Deny policies, SCPs, or boundary conditions that might restrict this action.
